# Is the below given code is wrong?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf(scanf("%d",&a));
    return 0;
}
```

I got this message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: You are passing the int return from scanf into printf(), which is expecting a string pointer as the first argument: BANG.  Don't write 'clever' code - it just causes problems.

Comment: You don't provide a format specifier for `printf`. Ex: `printf("%d", scanf("%d",&a));` Of course, that won't print what you think it will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format for `printf()` function is :-

```
printf(const char *format, ...)
```

You have to provide a **string** (*format string with  format specifiers*) as argument for function `printf()`.

You may Try :-

```
printf("%d",scanf("%d",&a)); // with format string
```

This will print **1** if scanning is successful . Here `%d` in *format string* for `integer` parameter.

To read and print variable `a` , Try :-

```
 scanf("%d",&a);  // reading
 printf("%d",a);  // printing
```

Answer (score 2):

Read your compiler warnings.

```
prog.c:8:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     printf(scanf("%d",&a));
            ^~~~~
```

`printf` wants a string as first argument. You're giving it an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print 'a', so you should do this way

```
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d", a);
```

The `scanf()` return the total number of characters written [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` looks at your format string, sees `%d` and matches it to the *address of an `int`*, which you provided with `&a`.  `scanf` will return `EOF` if there is an error while trying to read a value, else it will return the number of items successfully matched as an `int`.  For example, if you typed `123`, `scanf("%d", &a) == 1` is true, but if you typed `q123`, `scanf("%d", &a) == 0` is true.

`printf` requires a format string just like `scanf`, and it uses that format to print the values of the arguments.  It has no way of knowing that the format used for `scanf` is the same format you wanted to use for printing too, and you did not provide a string, which is a kind of pointer, containing the format for printing your arguments.  This is the problem with your code.

Integers, such as the `int` value that `scanf` returns, can be converted to pointers without you telling the compiler to perform the conversion.  As a consequence, a compiler can complain that you're doing something potentially problematic (*warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast*), but that code will be allowed to compile and execute.

When you see a warning like that, look at what type the function requires for that argument and the type of the value you used as that argument.  Chances are very good that the compiler is trying to help you avoid a mistake like `printf(scanf("%d", &a));`