# Why is integer implicitly casted to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51918622/6699433) with this statement: `printf(scanf("%d",&a));`

Of course it generates the warning `passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast.`

I know perfectly well what's wrong with this statement. That is not the question.

But it got me wondering. I perfectly understand why implicit casts between floats and integers is allowed even though it is error prone, but I cannot see why it is allowed from integer to pointer. When would you ever what to do cast an integer to a pointer?

Comment: There is no such thing as "implicit cast". A cast is an explicit type conversion.

Comment: Note: When the _null pointer constant_ `NULL` is `0`, an `int`, code like `some_type *p = NULL);` is an implicit conversion of an `int` to a pointer.  Fairly common code.  Other times `NULL` is something like `((void*)0)`, an _expclit_ cast of an `int` to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I perfectly understand why implicit casts between floats and integers is allowed even though it is error prone, but I cannot see why it is allowed from integer to pointer. When would you ever what to do this?

Consider a piece of software that needs to access a specific address. Let's say a bootloader wanting to get a handle on the VGA text mode buffer, which resides at the physical address `0xB8000`.

```
uint16_t * terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*)0xB8000;
```

This line casts the *integer* `0xB8000` to pointer *with* a cast, which is perfectly legal. If you *omit* the cast, there is some possibility that you're not doing what you *think* you're doing (as with your `printf( scanf( ... ) )` example), which is why the compiler emits a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This statement does not have any sense.

`scanf` returns an integer - the number of successfully scanned items. In your case it will be zero (no success) or 1.

`printf` needs the pointer to the string containing format and zero or more another parameters.

`printf(scanf("%d",&a))` passes the the result of the scanf (zero or 1) as pointer to the format string. As it is not valid pointer this statement is the UB.

implicit cast from the integer to the pointer is usually a programmer error but is legal from the language point of view. As this kind of cast is suspicius, the compiler emits the warning. Casts from unsigned integers to pointers (explicit) are often used in the micro controller programming - for example

`((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x4000000)`
otherwise it would be extremely difficult to access the particular addresses in the memory. How this kind if  cast behaves is implementation defined.

In your case you probably meant `printf("%d\n", scanf("%d",&a));` which will print the number of the scanned items from the format.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I think you should rewrite your answer a little bit to put focus on what you wrote about microcontrollers. The rest has nothing to do with my question, and could possibly be interesting as side info.

Comment: More likely `scanf(...); printf("%d\n", a);`